# Github action Azure login token is expired

Tags: azure, authentication, github-actions

I'm using the azure/login github action in my workflow to login to azure to then set some secrets and deploy to Azure Kubernetes Cluster. Suddenly the github action is failing with the error **token is expired**.

The last thing I did before this error started showing up "not sure if this is related at all" was to execute the command `az vmss identity assign -g` on the vmss of the cluster to assign a userAssignedIdentity

[image]

I tried recreated the federated credential for the enterprise app connecting the github actions/workflows to our AAD but nothing changed, I even tried using a client secret authentication, but that gave the same error as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something was seriously messed up with the cluster, I had to delete it and recreate and recreate the managed identity, granting it access to the cluster and creating a federated credential to allow github to deploy through it to the cluster